# Overridden spock test methods still running

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have a series of classes that extend from a base class. I've written spock tests classes for the classes with a base test class which  tests normal functionality but in the case of a few classes the standard test logic does not work.

My plan was to simply override the base test methods when needed, but it appears that spock still runs them.

Example:

Base test:

```
def "testing name"() {
     expect:
     assert STANDARD CODE HERE
}
```

Subclass test:

```
def "testing name"() {
     expect:
     assert CUSTOM CODE HERE
}
```

But when I run the test, the base test's method is still running and failing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Spock 0.7, overriding test methods in subclasses isn't supported, and you'll have to find a different way to structure your tests. For example, you could use the template method pattern, where a test method in the base class calls some abstract or concrete helper methods, which are then implemented or overridden in subclasses.

Comment: That is disappointing. I can see value in not overriding at times, but it is also a great way to be able to manage variation without resorting to more complex template methods. An annotation to control the behavior could be nice.

Comment: Has this changed at all for Spock 1.0? It would allow for some really tight test code with minimal boilerplate if we could use more of the OO goodness for this. Would Traits or Mixins be a workable option for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can make the original feature return early on a condition:

```
class BaseSpec extends Specification
    @Shared
    def ignored = [:]     {

    def myTest(){
        if (ignored['myTest']) return
        ...
    }
```

}

The derived class can set the ignore in the setupSpec:

```
class DerivedSpec extends BaseSpec
    def setupSpec() {
        ignored['myTest'] = true
    }
    def myTest(){
        //override
    }
}
```

Ugly, but it works.